# C++ verify creditcard via LUHN Formula (Loop & SumToken Error)

Tags: c++, loops, credit-card, luhn, quincykit

I used to be coding with C#, I'm learning C++ at UOW currently.
There's this assignment that im supposed to verify a credit card whether its valid via modulus 10 (LUHN formula)
However I didn't manage to get the correct answer as displayed/required by the lecturer. 
The below are my C++ efforts for this assignment. Do advise, cheers.

Problem1 - Loop error / infinite
Problem2 - sum of 4 tokens (Digits) I got are incorrect I believe.
Problem3 - Any advice to improve on this coding (without changing too much) - just to make it more efficient.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Get Reverse of an int
int getReverse(int);

// Double 2nd and 4th digit
int newDigits (int);

// Sum Token up
int sumToken (int);

// Modulus 10 Verification
bool verifyToken (int);

int main()
{
    int card,card1, card2, card3, card4;
    int cardReverseD, cardReverseC, cardReverseB, cardReverseA;
    int reverseA, reverseB, reverseC, reverseD;
    int newNumber4, newNumber3, newNumber2, newNumber1;
    int sumToken4, sumToken3, sumToken2, sumToken1;
    int sumTokenFinal; // Used for data verification via modulus 10
    char again; // For loop

    cout << "Welcome to Marcus Moo Legal Licensed Money Lender Card Company" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Enter Credit Card Number
    do 
    {
    cout << "Enter credit card number: ";

    // Fourth (4th) Card Number
    cin >> card4;
    cin.ignore(1,'-');

    cardReverseD = getReverse(card4);

    newNumber4 = newDigits(cardReverseD); // new int after double 2nd and 4th digit
    sumToken4 = sumToken(newNumber4); // sum of token of sector 4

    // Third(3rd) Card Number
    cin >> card3;
    cin.ignore(1,'-');

    cardReverseC = getReverse(card3);

    newNumber3 = newDigits(cardReverseC); // new int after double 2nd and 4th digit
    sumToken3 = sumToken(newNumber3); // sum of token of sector 3      

    // Second(2nd) Card Number
    cin >> card2;
    cin.ignore(1,'-');

    cardReverseB = getReverse(card2);

    newNumber2 = newDigits(cardReverseB); // new int after double 2nd and 4th digit
    sumToken2 = sumToken(newNumber2); // sum of token of sector 2     

    // First(1st) Card Number
    cin >> card1;

    cardReverseA = getReverse(card1);

    newNumber1 = newDigits(cardReverseA); // new int after double 2nd and 4th digit
    sumToken1 = sumToken(newNumber1); // sum of token of sector 1    

    // Addition of 1-4 tokens NEW & Verification & COUT
    sumTokenFinal = sumToken1 + sumToken2 + sumToken3 + sumToken4; 

    cout << "The special sum is " << sumTokenFinal << endl;

    if (verifyToken(sumTokenFinal)==true)
    {
        cout << card1 << "-" << card2 << "-" << card3 << "-" << card4
        << " is a valid credit card number" << endl;
    }     
    else 
    {
        cout << card1 << "-" << card2 << "-" << card3 << "-" << card4
        << " is not a valid credit card number" << endl;
    }

    // Let loop go again?

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Another Card (y/Y/n/N): ";
    cin.get(again);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    } while ((again='y')||(again='Y')&&(again!='n')&&(again!='N'));
}

// Get Reverse of an int
int getReverse(int x)
{
    int reverse=0;
    int lastDigit;
    while (x>0)
    {
        lastDigit = x%10;
        reverse = (reverse*10)+lastDigit;
        x = x/10;
    }
    return reverse;
}

// Double 2nd and 4th digit
int newDigits (int x)
{
    int newNumber, length;
    int secondDigit, fourthDigit;
    secondDigit = x%1000/100*2;
    fourthDigit = x%10*2; // Edited as per advised
    if ((secondDigit<10)&&(fourthDigit<10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*1000)+(secondDigit*100)+(x%100/10*10)+(fourthDigit);
    }
    else if ((secondDigit>10)&&(fourthDigit<10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*10000)+(secondDigit*100)+(x%100/10*10)+(fourthDigit);
    }
    else if ((secondDigit<10)&&(fourthDigit>10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*10000)+(secondDigit*1000)+(x%100/10*100)+(fourthDigit);
    }
    else if ((secondDigit>10)&&(fourthDigit>10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*100000)+(secondDigit*1000)+(x%100/10*100)+(fourthDigit);
    }

    return newNumber;
}

// Sum Token up
int sumToken (int x)
{
    int lastDigit;
    int sumDigits=0;
    while (x>0)
    {
        lastDigit = x % 10;
        sumDigits += lastDigit;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return sumDigits;
}

// Modulus 10 Verification
bool verifyToken (int x)
{
    bool verify = false;

    if (x%10==0)
    {
        verify = true;    
    }
    return verify;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks! I'll try this out!

Comment: `secondDigit` and `fourthDigit` have the same definition. That can't be right.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'll edit that portion! Eagle eyes buddy

Comment: You can reduce your character comparisons by half by using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower`.