# How do I retain value of original x while using x to do calculations?

Tags: c++, variables, static

I wish to retain value of original value of X while doing calculations with X, how do i do it? Do advise! Cheers!
//addon
I got the solution to my question via helpful stackoverflowpeeps. I initially thought x will change in value everytime i modulus or divide it. However they describe explain to me via pass by value!

Do refer to [C++ verify creditcard via LUHN Formula (Loop & SumToken Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144329/c-verify-creditcard-via-luhn-formula-loop-sumtoken-error) to see how I utilized the function.

```
int newDigits (int x)
{
    int newNumber, length;
    int secondDigit, fourthDigit;
    secondDigit = x%1000/100*2;
    fourthDigit = x%10*2; // Edited as per advised
    if ((secondDigit<10)&&(fourthDigit<10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*1000)+(secondDigit*100)+(x%100/10*10)+(fourthDigit);
    }
    else if ((secondDigit>10)&&(fourthDigit<10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*10000)+(secondDigit*100)+(x%100/10*10)+(fourthDigit);
    }
    else if ((secondDigit<10)&&(fourthDigit>10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*10000)+(secondDigit*1000)+(x%100/10*100)+(fourthDigit);
    }
    else if ((secondDigit>10)&&(fourthDigit>10))
    {
        newNumber = (x%10000/1000*100000)+(secondDigit*1000)+(x%100/10*100)+(fourthDigit);
    }

    return newNumber;
}
```

Comment: Make a copy before you modify it?

Comment: In your post `x` does not change.

Comment: Where is `x` being modified?

Comment: `x` is a copy anyway.

Comment: i suspect this is an XY question

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
this is a function in the coding
e.g. newNumber = newDigits(variable); - to get a newNumber with this function

Comment: You are on the right path.  Do nothing, and *you retain* the value of original x.

Comment: @MikeNakis
however mike 
e.g. 
x = 123;
x % 100  // 23
x *100 // 230
So value keeps changing ?

Comment: @KayzelMoo Maybe you should post the actual code you're referring to.  It is confusing posting code as a question, and then posting the code you're really concerned with in the comment section.  The code you posted as a question does no modification of `x`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144329/c-verify-creditcard-via-luhn-formula-loop-sumtoken-error

Comment: The `x` is passed by value, meaning it is a *copy* of the variable you're passing in.  Nothing is modified.

Comment: @pm100 yeah , the "Y" is "How do I commit credit card fraud" :D

Comment: @KayzelMoo Why do you think that `x+1` changes the value of `x`? Does `3+1` change the value of `3`?

Comment: @immibis enlightenment. thanks

Comment: @KayzelMoo Also [No modification when passed by value](http://ideone.com/aaOCUT).

Comment: ask your question again, explaining what your actual problem is (ie the behavior you are getting that you dont expect / want) and post the code that shows it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not modifying the value of `x` anywhere in your function `int newDigits (int x)`. You are only using the value stored in x to perform other calculations; these caculations do not change the value stored in x at all. The lines in your code where x is used:

```
    secondDigit = x%1000/100*2;
    fourthDigit = x%10*2;
    newNumber = (x%10000/1000*1000)+(secondDigit*100)+(x%100/10*10)+(fourthDigit);
    newNumber = (x%10000/1000*10000)+(secondDigit*100)+(x%100/10*10)+(fourthDigit);
    newNumber = (x%10000/1000*10000)+(secondDigit*1000)+(x%100/10*100)+(fourthDigit);
    newNumber = (x%10000/1000*100000)+(secondDigit*1000)+(x%100/10*100)+(fourthDigit);
```

do nothing to change the value of x; x is the same at the end of these operations. The value of x can only be changed if you do something like

> x += a
>
> x++
>
> x -= a
>
> x *= a
>
> x /= a
>
> etc... (assume a to be a constant integer)

Simply doing something like:

```
    int a = (x + 2) / x;
```

won't change the value of `x`.

However, if you want to ensure that the value that is passed in `x` is saved, then you can do it in 2 ways:

---

**The first method** is to use the `const` in front of x, like you mention in your question. This solves your problem of retaining the value of x throughout the function; however, it also means that you cannot change the value of x (if you have to). In that case, unless you are completely sure that you will not and do not want to modify x, then you can use this method. If you decide to use a constant, then change your function declaration to:

```
    int newDigits (const int x)
```

**The second method** would be to simply declare another variable of type `int` at the start of your function and set it equal to x, like:

```
    int newDigits (int x)
    {
        int y = x; // This way, you do can modify x knowing that you can look back to y if you need the original value
        
        // Rest of the function code
    }
```

---

Based on the link you've posted about the rest of your code, I'm not sure what you want us to do with it; it makes no difference to my answer. If you need any more clarification, let me know in the comments box.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment in c++ is generally value driven. The statement `int x = y;` *copies* the value of `y` into `x`. That is, `x` now has the value that `y` had when it was assigned. Further changes to `y`, after the assignment to `x`, will not change the value of `x`. If you *want* `x` to forever refer to the value of `y`, you need to use a reference, denoted by an ampersand, like this `int & x = y;`.

In your case, `int newDigits (int x)` takes `x` as a copy of whatever you provided when calling `newDigits`. Nothing you do within `newDigits` can affect the original value given to `newDigits`.

The use of `const` simply means that you cannot modify the value. `const int x` would prevent you from changing the current value of `x`. It isn't necessary here to preserve the value given to `newDigits`, since we already can't modify it in this case. If `x` *was* a reference (`int & x`) then adding `const` would indeed prevent you from accidentally changing the original value that was given to `newDigits`.

Note that in your example, `x` is never actually modified at all.

Comment: Do refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144329/c-verify-creditcard-via-luhn-formula-loop-sumtoken-error for better understanding

Comment: @KayzelMoo If there is something I misunderstood, please point it out. I've looked at the referred question but I don't see what extra information am I expected to gain from it.

Comment: secondDigit = x%1000/100*2;
 fourthDigit = x%10*2;

Does x change in value before it move to calculate fourthdigit?

Comment: @KayzelMoo No, using a variable of type `int` in an expression does not change it, unless it's an assignment operation, such as `=`, `+=`, `<<=`, etc.

Comment: Thanks!! Appreciate it!